.NET MAUI Unable to Install / Debug from Visual Studio 2022 on Physical Device
I have a Xamarin Android app already installed on a physical device.
If I attempt to launch the new MAUI version of that same app, the deployment fails with the following message:
Detecting existing process
> am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.mycompany.myapp/crc64ce82217b4e30774f.MainActivity"
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.mycompany.myapp/crc64ce82217b4e30774f.MainActivity }

Exception occurred while executing 'start':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.mycompany.myapp/crc64ce82217b4e30774f.MainActivity } from null (pid=9815, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10860


How can I successfully install and debug from Visual Studio, in order to test the upgrade process from the old version of the app?  This is also important in order to ensure it is possible to upgrade and preserve the data in the old version.

UPDATE:
If I create an APK from a release version and attempt to side load that on the mobile device where the previous version of the app is installed, I get this error message after being prompted if I want to upgrade:

Surely there HAS to be a way to upgrade from the older Xamarin version of app?

In your MainActivity try setting Exported = true

@NongthonbamTonthoi : Yes.  This did not make a difference for me.

See UPDATE in original post...

Have you completed the migration of the project from Xamarin.Android to .Net Maui? (For more information on how to upgrade, you can refer to .NET Upgrade Assistant) Does the project work properly on simulator?

Android has multiple user features. You can see it in the Status Bar. Switching to the new user and deleting the conflicting application may be a solution. Sometimes apps you can't see appear installed on the second user. I had a similar situation before I was able to solve it this way. Just a solution suggestion. You should alos make sure that you sign with the same signature and upgrade your version or build nuumber.

This is a ported MAUI version of a Xamarin app.  The application ID (com.{company}.{app}) is identical, as is the GUID associated with it.  The internal version number is rev'd up from the Xamarin version so as to allow an upgrade.   When I tap the APK I am prompted "do you want to upgrade"... but then upgrade fails due to a conflicting app (the old Xarmarin app).  This seems like errant behavior.   We can't ship the MAUI version without a smooth upgrade.  Hoping someone has a solution.
